# Readable KeyStroke

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

Is there any default way in `Java` to translate `KeyStroke` to readable `String` except manual parsing?

```
KeyStroke ke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl released 1");
System.out.println(ke.toString())

Print result:
ctrl released 1

Expected:
Ctrl+1
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/KeyStroketoString.htm or http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/Swing_Event/KeyStroke

Comment: *>except manual parsing*

Comment: The format you want is a custom format, so obviously you would need to do manual parsing or formatting.

Comment: @camickr thanks for mKorbel' translation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Java Swing API`:

```
KeyStroke accelerator =  b.getAccelerator();
String acceleratorText = "";
if (accelerator != null) {
    int modifiers = accelerator.getModifiers();
    if (modifiers > 0) {
        acceleratorText = KeyEvent.getKeyModifiersText(modifiers);
        acceleratorText += "+";
    }
    acceleratorText += KeyEvent.getKeyText(accelerator.getKeyCode());
}
```

@mKorbel, U're wrong and groundless saying that it isn't a part of defaults